# Is it possible to deploy a MEAN stack application using SFTP?

Tags: angular, express, ftp, sftp, mean-stack

I have been trying to deploy a basic eCommerce store to a server using WinSCP for SFTP deployment. I have tried following a lot of guides such as building a `dist` folder and changing environment to `production`. This method keeps coming up particularly for Angular application deployment. However, despite my efforts, I can not get the MEAN store to work after uploading the project to the server using SFTP.

The server seems to only process the main index.html file with `<app-root>LOADING...</app-root>`, but does not process the rest of the website or any of the express, node or MongoDB information.

Any suggestions?

Comment: yes it is possible , and error  must be related to `base`  make sure you have set the correct `<base href="/">` according tot your setup

Comment: My goodness. I haven't even done anything related to `base`. Can you recommend a suitable tutorial or something or how I should properly implement `base`?

Comment: here is a example article , it may help : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Comment: It appears the `<base href="/">` was already created when I used `ng build --prod`. It is visible in not only my complete project, but also the generated folder 'public` which has various `index.html`, `main.bundle.js` etc. files in it. I am not sure what I am missing as I still have the same blank page. I also have a 'dist' folder but that contains some .js files and doesn't look like your typical 'dist' folder when using `ng build`.